# How to Extract parent value on the basis of Child Json parameters where multiple child units are present

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have to extract multiple correlating variables from a response (which is json) in JMeter. Part of the response is listed below:

I have tried    $..[?(@.sType == '7')].tId but its not worked for me

To proceed with the next request, I have to extract tId (2309), on the basis of " Stype = 7 " There are several units, each unit has several children and each children has several contents. Each content id matches just one children id and each children id matches just one unit id. Ids have to be selected on a random basis.

I've tried to extract all ids from the response and use them randomly, but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

Posting incomplete JSON is some form of disregard to the community, you're supposed to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) yourself, I'll note your username and it will be the last time you're having support from me.

Coming back to your question:

Try something like:

```
topics.*[?(@.tSections[3].sType == 7)].tId
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Thank you much Dmitri T and sorry for Incorrect Json I have removed that Json but Solutions you provided is very helpful     $..topics.*[?(@.tSections[3].sType == 7)].tId   is working for me

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get parent of a JSON node using `JSON Extractor`. you will need to write custom code in groovy / javascript with for-loops